# No output to standard out for Java Process

Tags: java, inputstream, processbuilder

I am executing mysql.exe form a java process (in Windows 10, JDK 1.8 env.), the code is as below:

```
String command="D:\\SW\\MySQL_8\\bin\\mysql.exe --user=root --password=password";

ProcessBuilder pBuilder=new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
pBuilder=pBuilder.redirectOutput(new File("D:\\workspaces\\cas\\CASCAppliance_Common\\out\\out.txt"));
pBuilder=pBuilder.redirectError(new File("D:\\workspaces\\cas\\CASCAppliance_Common\\out\\err.txt"));

Process p=pBuilder.start();
OutputStream os=p.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(os);
```

If I execute mysql.exe from command line, I get the below output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\SW>cd MySQL_8\bin

D:\SW\MySQL_8\bin>mysql --user=root --password=password
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.11 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I have tried to get the input stream from the process after error stream redirection, I only get the below:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

I have also tried redirecting the err and std out to files, still the err file contains the above text and the std out file contains nothing.

On the other hand, If I execute cmd.exe and run a command, say 'dir', I am getting the required directory listing from the InputStream of the process.

My question is, am I doing something wrong or is mysql.exe executing in a way that it is not possible to get the above output from the input stream of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is about mysql. ( edit is updates from @dave_thompson_085)

If one runs mysql from an interactive shell but redirect input and/or output, it suppresses banner, prompting, table-boxing, and the 'N row(s) (X sec)' trailer.

Note even without prompting it still reads SQL statements and executes them, and displays any result set -- although if output is a pipe it buffers. Conversely if in a Java process that has stdin and stdout on a terminal, one runs mysql inheriting those, it has the full interactive behaviour.

Comment: @Iscoughlin, thanks for the answer, based on it, I went through the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/agents/replication-agents-overview?view=sql-server-2017 of replication agents, could you please elaborate a bit on your answer (I am not very familiar with MS architecture). In addition, (though I have not tried it), would I also face the same problem in Linux environment (say CentOS).

Comment: It's not where you launch from, but what you provide for I/O. If I run mysql from an interactive shell but redirect input and/or output, it suppresses banner, prompting, table-boxing, and the 'N row(s) (X sec)' trailer. Note even without prompting it still reads SQL statements and executes them, and displays any result set -- although if output is a pipe it buffers. Conversely if in a Java process that has stdin and stdout on a terminal, I run mysql inheriting those, it has the full interactive behavior.

Comment: @Ironluca: he meant REPL = Read-Eval-Print-Loop, a description of some interactive programs like shell, ed, CMD or Powershell, many classic BASIC systems, and the mysql client program, among others. This is entirely unrelated to replication, plus your link is for Microsoft SQLServer which has nothing to do with MySQL.